# Subversion polling returns an error as "Unknownhost" in jenkins but job is working when you triggered manually

Tags: jenkins

I have configured jenkins and enabled subversion then entered URL and its credentials in the jenkins job.If i triggered the jenkins build manually,check out the svn code is suceess but when there is change in the SVN,job is triggered through SCM polling but it returns an error

Error:ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for http://
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: unknown host
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/repos/systemsengineering1/active/layered_arch/product/cpAt/at_invecas/trunk/'